# Primeng p-chips: unable to add object dynamically

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm passing an array of objects `value1` to the `p-chips` component.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { 
    values1: any[] = [{key:'1', value:'one'}];
    key: string;
    value: string;
    
    add() {
      this.values1.push({key: this.key, value:this.value});
      console.log(this.values1);
    }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="p-fluid">
  <h5>Basic</h5>
  <p-chips field="value" [(ngModel)]="values1" ></p-chips>
  Add key
   <input id="key" type="text" [(ngModel)]="key" />
  <br/>
  Add value
  <input id="value" type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" />
  <button (click)="add()">Add</button>
</div>
```

The initial value `{key:'1', value:'one'}` gets reflected in p-chips.
However, if I call `add` function to add an object to the variable `value1`,
the new objects gets added to the `value1` but it does not reflect in `p-chips`

Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-chips-demo-qxhcec?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**EDIT**: I clicked on the `p-chips` template after adding the object and the objects were reflected, but how can it be done automatically without any click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't push to the array, create a new one instead.. this has to do with change detection and how this component is implemented:

```
add() {
      this.values1 = [...this.values1, {key: this.key, value:this.value}]
      console.log(this.values1);
    }
```

Comment: Is that the best practice to reassign the array every time when I add?

Comment: For primeng I would say it is. They listen to object reference change on inputs instead of doing deep checks. It is certainly faster to work with immutable objects since a simple reference check is enough to notice change, while looping over a big array to check if some item has been altered can take up more time.